# Esconder campos do form que vão ser requeridos

Tags: c#, jquery, html

Olá, eu tenho um form que dependendo do que vai ser selecionado em um select vai esconder ou exibir campos. O problema é que alguns desses campos serão do tipo **required** e o submit não vai se completar se eles estiverem escondidos e sem valores, estou usando a função abaixo para esconde-los mas como posso tratar os campos required que precisarei adicionar?

```js
    $('.PessoaFisica').hide();
    $('#tipoPessoa').change(function () {
        if ($('#tipoPessoa').val() == 'pf') {
            $('.PessoaJuridica').hide();
            $('.PessoaFisica').show();
        }
        else {
            $('.PessoaJuridica').show();
            $('.PessoaFisica').hide();
        }
    });
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
  
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h3>Transportadoras</h3>

        <div class="panel panel-default item-padding">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="tipoPessoa">Pessoa física ou jurídica?</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="tipoPessoa" name="tipoPessoa">
                                    <option value="pj" selected>Pessoa Juridica</option>
                                    <option value="pf">Pessoa Física</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group PessoaFisica">
                                <label for="cpf">CPF</label>
                                <input id="cpf" name="cpf" class="form-control" type="text" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group PessoaJuridica">
                                <label for="cpf">CNPJ</label>
                                <input id="cpf" name="cpf" class="form-control" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="codigoANTT">Código da ANTT</label>
                                <input id="codigoANTT" name="codigoANTT" class="form-control" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="row PessoaJuridica">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nomeFantasia">Nome Fantasia</label>
                                <input id="nomeFantasia" name="nomeFantasia" class="form-control" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="razaoSocial">Razão Social</label>
                                <input id="razaoSocial" name="razaoSocial" class="form-control" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row PessoaJuridica">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="incricaoMunicioal">Inscrição Municipal</label>
                                <input id="incricaoMunicioal" name="incricaoMunicioal" class="form-control" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inscricaoEstadual">Inscrição Estadual</label>
                                <input id="inscricaoEstadual" name="inscricaoEstadual" class="form-control" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row PessoaFisica">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                                <input id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="page-header"><h4>Endereço</h4></div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="cep">CEP</label>
                                <input id="cep" name="cep" class="form-control" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="logradouro">Logradouro</label>
                                <input id="logradouro" name="logradouro" class="form-control" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="numero">Número</label>
                                <input id="numero" name="numero" class="form-control" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="complemento">Complemento</label>
                                <input id="complemento" name="complemento" class="form-control" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <br />

                    <div class="row pull-right">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn">Voltar</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn">Salvar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta usar o `removeAttr()` para remover (caso você use o *required* do html5), 
e usa o `.prop()` para adicionar novamente.  Ex:

Html:

```
 <input id="cpf" name="cpf" class="form-control" type="text" required/>
```

JS:

```
$('.PessoaFisica').hide();
$('#tipoPessoa').change(function () {
    if ($('#tipoPessoa').val() == 'pf') {
        $('.PessoaJuridica').hide();
        $('.PessoaJuridica').removeAttr('required');
        $('.PessoaFisica').show();
        $('.PessoaFisica').prop('required',true);
    }
    else {
        $('.PessoaJuridica').show();
        $('.PessoaJuridica').prop('required',true);
        $('.PessoaFisica').hide();
        $('.PessoaFisica').removeAttr('required');
    }
});
```

Comment: Obrigado, cara! Acho que vai resolver meu problema assim mesmo!